# Why does a Cassandra node get picked as coordinator even when the driver keeps throwing OperationTimedOutException?

Tags: cassandra

I set up a Cassandra cluster with several coordinator nodes.

Sometimes one of the coordinator nodes becomes unavailable...my code handles this with a retry policy which moves to the next node and the problem is solved.

However, it seems that the problematic node still receives traffic even if the driver keeps throwing OperationTimedOutException...it is a time consuming since this node useless.

Further details:
Cassandra Driver -
I'm using Cassandra driver version 3.11.0 (cassandra-driver-core-3.11.0.jar)
Loading balancing policy -
I didn't set any load balancing policy - thus, the default is used.
Retry Policy -
I implemented my own retry policy -
In case of read/write timeout or unavailable retry cause - I'm using retry while reducing the consistency level to one. In case of request error - I'm trying a different host.

Is there anyway to configure that if the driver keeps throwing OperationTimedOutException while sending query to a specific coordinator node, this node will not be called for some period of time?

Comment: I have multiple follow-up questions: (1) which driver are you using, and (2) which version? Also, which (3) load balancing policy and (4) retry policy have you configured? Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

Cassandra client connection does the Cassandra co-ordinator node caching. So, It will continue sending the query to the same node. Tune your application layer socket config with the client connection timeout.

```
SocketOptions options = new SocketOptions();
options.setConnectTimeoutMillis(30000);
options.setReadTimeoutMillis(30000);
options.setTcpNoDelay(true);
```

Comment: I'm curious as to what you're trying to achieve with your recommendation since increasing the timeout will not prevent the driver from routing requests to a node. Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

There are a few misconceptions in your question so let me begin by correcting them.

**Misconception #1**

> I set up a Cassandra cluster with several coordinator nodes.

All nodes in a Cassandra cluster are the same. This is one of the attributes that makes Cassandra awesome. Any node in the cluster can be picked as a coordinator. You can NOT configure/nominate/setup a node to be a coordinator while others aren't.

**Misconception #2**

> ... if a coordinator node keeps throwing OperationTimedOutException ...

Cassandra nodes are not capable of throwing `OperationTimedOutException`. `OperationTimedOutException` is a client-side exception which gets thrown by the driver when it doesn't get a response from a coordinator within the configured client timeout period.

It is a different exception from read or write timeout exceptions which are thrown when the coordinator sends a response back to the driver when a read or write request timed out on the server-side.

**Picking nodes**

You didn't specify which driver + version you're using. [`OperationTimedOutException` is in Java driver v3.x](https://docs.datastax.com/en/drivers/java/3.11/com/datastax/driver/core/exceptions/OperationTimedOutException.html) but not in v4.x (it was [replaced with `DriverTimeoutException`](https://docs.datastax.com/en/drivers/java/4.14/com/datastax/oss/driver/api/core/DriverTimeoutException.html) which makes it clearer that the exception is client-side) so for the purposes of my response, I'm going to assume that you're using Java driver v3.11 (latest in the v3 series).

You also didn't specify which [load balancing policies](https://docs.datastax.com/en/developer/java-driver/3.11/manual/load_balancing/) (LBP) you've configured and which [retry policies](https://docs.datastax.com/en/developer/java-driver/3.11/manual/retries/). If you're using [the latency-aware LBP `LatencyAwarePolicy`,](https://docs.datastax.com/en/developer/java-driver/3.11/manual/load_balancing/#latency-aware-policy) the likely scenario is that the problematic node has the lowest latency so it is listed as the "preferred node" by the policy.

Handling misbehaving nodes is a very tough thing to do for the drivers, particularly if the nodes are unresponsive because a driver won't know what is really going on if a node doesn't respond at all. The drivers can't be too aggressive at marking nodes as "down" because if the node is just temporarily unavailable (for example, due to a GC pause), it won't get picked again as a coordinator for a bit of time.

Sometimes, the latency "signal" from a problematic node takes a while to bubble up for a driver to effectively route around it because of the algorithm used by the driver to average out the reported latencies over a period of one or two minutes, scaled such that older latencies are weighted less than newer latencies. In the case of an unresponsive node, the driver can only base the average/scaling on the last time the node reported its latency.

For this reason, the `LatencyAwarePolicy` was dropped in Java driver v4 in preference for [the new `DefaultLoadBalancingPolicy`](https://docs.datastax.com/en/developer/java-driver/latest/manual/core/load_balancing/) which has a much better detection algorithm for slow replicas.

Your workaround using `tryNextHost()` is a bit clunky because you have to effectively wait for the retry policy to kick in. What you really need to focus on is the fact that your nodes become unresponsive. If your cluster is getting overloaded, you should consider increasing the capacity by adding more nodes.

Trying to come up with a software solution for what is an infrastructure capacity issue is never going to be successful in the long run. Cheers!

Comment: Thanks! I edited the question (of course, if the node is unavailable - the node itself cannot return anything)

So what do you suggest when it comes to the software?
Assuming that I keep the same driver version - should I change the load balancing policy from the default? or any solution that you can thing of?

Assuming that I'll update the driver version - should I use the suggested load balancing policy?